# How to get xml parentNode attribute value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an xml like below.

```
var myXml = new XmlDOM(false);
var xmlval = "<ParentNode Symbol="$"><Row book = "test" price ="80"/>   </ParentNode>";
myXml.LoadXML(xmlval);
```

How to get Symbol value from above xml.

i tried with myXml.getAttribute etc.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
var xmlval = '<ParentNode Symbol="$"><Row book = "test" price ="80"/>   </ParentNode>';
var symbol = $(xmlval).attr('Symbol');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UX7ZN/1

Comment: don't you need to escape the quotes in `xmlval`?

Comment: yes, I've fixed it in the JSFIDDLE, but forgot to update sample. Thanks.